# Is is possible in Rust to invoke a macro in procedure macro code?

Tags: rust

For example, I have a procedure macro attribute on a `impl` block like this, normally it handles methods:

```rust
#[my_proc_macro]
impl Foo {
  pub fn bar1() {}
  pub fn bar2() {}
}
```

Now the macro user may not want to write these methods, instead, he wants to invoke a macro to produce these methods, like:

```rust
#[my_proc_macro]
impl Foo {
  generate_methods!();
}
```

Now `my_proc_macro` will be fed with the tokens of macro invocation, instead the tokens of macro invocation result.

My question is: is it possible to expand `generate_methods!()` inside `my_proc_macro`, and work with the produced methods?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is currently (Rust 1.44.1) **impossible**.

However, it's a known problem for quite some time already. The search term is "eager macro expansion". There is [this open RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2320) which was started in February 2018:

> Expose an API for procedural macros to opt in to eager expansion. This will:
>
> - Allow procedural and declarative macros to handle unexpanded macro calls that are passed as inputs,
> - Allow macros to access the results of macro calls that they construct themselves,
> - Enable macros to be used where the grammar currently forbids it.

So people are working on it, but I wouldn't count on getting this feature anytime soon. It's not an easy problem after all.